# What is the best practice for having several AWS Lambdas consuming an external(EC2) Postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I've +100 endpoints at AWS API each one calling a specific Lambda script, that connects to a external Postgres DB, that fetch the data and return it.

My question is, if I do that, 100 Lambdas scripts, will need to have in each one the connections details as environment variables?

That is probably not the way to do it... what is the best way to manage this in a single place, like Global Environment Variables that can be accessed to all the lambdas?

another thing is, every Lambda open a connection is very bad too, is there a way to manage a connection pool, that can be shared between other lambdas?

Is there anyway to group them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of storing secret configuration for access by AWS services like Lambda functions is [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/).  You store the connection details as a secret, and in each Lambda function code you load the value from the Secrets Manager service as and when you require it.

Lambda functions are deliberately isolated, and so there is no way to share connections or other resources between different functions.  You can sometimes share resources between successive invocations of the same function, but you can't rely on this and for something like a database connection it's not even a good usecase.  Instead, you should be trying to open and close the connection as compactly as possible, so that other function invocations can have access to the databases's connection pool.

Comment: Thanks! do you think that connect to a external database from Lambda is not a good usecase? Can you suggest what would be a good usecase then? thanks again!

Comment: Connecting to a database from a Lambda function to do something with the data is absolutely a good usecase _for Lambda_.  I only meant that caching the connection resource in the Lambda execution environment (to potentially be shared between separate invocations of the Lambda) is not prudent, because the connection will then be held open for an unknown time.

Comment: You can move the dbconnection object outside the lambda handler and this will cache it during subsequent executions as the same container is invoked (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/), you can avoid 100's of api calls to the secret manger (if the dbconn object is not null) in case the executions are at a high rate.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, this (whether or not to cache things in the execution context outside the runtime context) is exactly what we're talking about.  I agree it would be beneficial to cache the connection string loaded from Secrets Manager,  as this can reduce function execution time and costs.  But caching the open database connection is not such a good idea, because it locks a connection into a container that will then get 'frozen', for an unknown length of time.